# Openstack Deployment Fails with Command openstack undercloud install

Tags: openstack, tripleo

I been trying to install openstack Undercloud but failed, there were different reassons but the last reason was, I am attaching [Logfile](https://gist.github.com/zeeshanalisyed/201ae90b2195c955ce9af6710850c9f3#file-install-undercloud-log) here. I am a beginner could not find any help online. This is my undercloud.conf file is given below.

```
[DEFAULT]
local_ip = 192.168.0.105/24
undercloud_public_vip = 192.168.0.110
undercloud_admin_vip = 192.168.0.111
local_interface = enp0s3
masquerade_network = 192.168.0.0/24
dhcp_start = 192.168.0.100
dhcp_end = 192.168.0.150
network_cidr = 192.168.0.0/24
network_gateway = 192.168.0.105
inspection_iprange = 192.168.0.160,192.168.0.199
```

### List Of Errors

- puppet

  Errors:

  1. libfacter is not found

     Solution:
     Manually install ***puppetserver*** and ***puppet-agent*** from ***puppetlabs-release-pc1-el-7.noarch.rpm***
- facter

  Errors:

  1. error while loading shared libraries: leatherman_curl.so.1.3.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
     Solution: I had to downgrade leatherman with command

  ```sh
   $ sudo yum downgrade leatherman
  ```
- TASK [Output for sync deployment HostsEntryDeployment] or jq: error

  Errors:

  ```
    fatal: [undercloud]: FAILED! => {
      "msg": [
          {
              "stderr": [
                  "/bin/sh: /usr/libexec/os-refresh-config/configure.d/55-heat-config: No such file or directory",
                  "jq: error: Could not open file /var/lib/heat-config/deployed/bfd49af0-49b0-49f9-ae36-b976dfb4058d.notify.json: No such file or directory"
              ]
          },
          {
              "status_code": "2"
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

Json file is generated dynamically so the root of the problem must be

```
/usr/libexec/os-refresh-config/configure.d/55-heat-config: No 
such file or directory
```

Comment: How exactly does it fail? You talk about different failure reasons but don't mention them. What do you mean by "last reason"? Did you try several times and each time there was a different reason? The log you post is almost 6000 lines long; can you say which messages in the log are related to the failure?

Comment: Current Error that Irecieve is  **"jq: error: Could not open file /var/lib/heat-config/deployed/bfd49af0-49b0-49f9-ae36-b976dfb4058d.notify.json: No such file or directory"** with **status_code 2**